# Debian bookworm: Use both libunwind8 and libunwind-14?

Tags: debian, libc++, libunwind

I updated my container from debian bullseye to bookworm.

I used both [libunwind8](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libunwind8) (and [libunwind-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libunwind-dev)) and [libc++-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libc++-dev)

Since bookworm, libc++-dev depends on [libunwind-14-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libunwind-14-dev) (probably because it now supports std::basic_stacktrace). This is a conflict, because both bring the file [libunwind.so](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Flib%2Fx86_64-linux-gnu%2Flibunwind.so&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

Installing both will cause:

```
$ apt install libunwind-dev
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libc++-14-dev libc++-dev libunwind-14-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libunwind-dev
```

It seams like libunwind-14 is different to [libunwind8](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/docs.html). It has other/less interfaces. I could not find the documentation on libunwind-14.

Is there any way to use both libc++ and libunwind8?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, although I think it is not great:

Instead of installing it, extract it. I extracted it to /opt.

```
apt-get download libunwind8 libunwind-dev
dpkg --extract libunwind8*.deb /opt/libunwind
dpkg --extract libunwind-dev*.deb /opt/libunwind
```

You will need to extract both (even it libunwind8 installs correctly and has no conflicts) because libunwind-dev has symlinks that do not resolve otherwise.